# Hide alert box coming from Javascript in WP8 using web browser control

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

I am using Webbrowser control in my Windows Phone 8 app. Here i am calling a Java Script funcction like below:

```
browser.InvokeScript("callMyJavaScriptFunction");
```

This Javascript function is showing an alert box, In the app that alert box is becoming as MessageBox. I want hide that Alert coming from Javascript.

Here I can't change the code in the Javascript.

**How can i hide the alert box coming from the Javascript in my xaml.cs file?**

Comment: Can't you avoid calling MessageBox.Show?

Comment: This Message Box is coming from the Javascript so how can get access to that Message Box which is coming from javavscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hijack the default `window.alert` JavaScript function and make it do nothing. Here is how:

Subscribe to the `Navigated` event of the `WebBrowser` controle to be sure that you page is fully loaded before injecting the required script:

```
browser.Navigated += browser_Navigated;
```

Set the `window.alert` method to do nothing:

```
void browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string[] code = {"window.alert = function(message) { };"};
    browser.InvokeScript("eval", code);
}
```